# Splitting XML level according to XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Can I split a level of an XML document with an XPath expression into a list? I have this, for example:

```
<root>
  <test1 />
  <testX />
  <test2 />
  <test21 />
  <testX />
  <test3 />
</root>
```

So running it on this returns a list with `<test1 />`, `<test2 /><test21 />` and `<test3 />`.

There is not necessarily just one node between `<testX />`, there can be a varying number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the first element under root, and the first element that follows each "testX" element. Excepting those elements that are named "testX".

```
(/root/*[1] | /root/*['testX' = name(preceding-sibling::*[1]))[name() != 'testX']
```

Some MSDN links on XPath:

- [XPath Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)
- [Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)
- [XPath functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256138.aspx)

Comment: It is not necessarily every second node. There can be a verying number of elements between the textX elements

Comment: I've elaborated my initial question

Answer (score 0):

```
/root/*[not(self::testX)]
```

would select

```
<test1 />
<test2 />
<test21 />
<test3 />
```